# WooCommerce sticking sidebar under products in /shop

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

After some searching it seems this is a problem with WooCommerce and custom themes. Most of the questions/advice is how to remove the sidebar from the bottom, but I'm interested in just having it moved back to where it is supposed to be (on the left side).

You can see where the sidebar is supposed to be here:
http://www.pleasesendtell.com

And how it re-positions it on the shop page here:
http://www.pleasesendtell.com/shop

I have figured out how to remove it from the shop page by editing the wc-template-hooks file (by removing "add_action( 'woocommerce_sidebar', 'woocommerce_get_sidebar', 10 );
"), but I'm pretty stumped when it comes to simply getting it back to where its supposed to be.

If anyone has any ideas I'm all ears!

Answer (score 0):

Just had a look, both pages have the sidebar in the same place for me. Using Win 7 / Chrome.